# Is dhammakaya a synonym of 'real nature of things'?

Tags: terminology

Is it correct to say that *dhammakaya* (the sum of all Buddha's teachings) is a synonym of 'the real nature of reality'?

Comment: The word "dhammakaya" is used in (or used by) more than one school of Buddhism, e.g. [Theravada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhammakaya_Movement) and [Mahayana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/11757/254).

Comment: Related question: [Can we consider 'tathagatagarbha' and 'dhammakaya' as synonyms?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10429/254)

Comment: More like "the teachings/body of knowledge on the real nature of reality" if referring to the Theravada definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no, not a synonym, but related. The Dharmakaya (in Sanskrit) is the Truth Body of Buddha. I believe it has the most significance in Mahayana Buddhism where it refers to the purified very subtle body which has the nature of bliss and is mixed inseparably with emptiness. 
The real nature of reality is that phenomena lack, or are empty of, true, independent existence.